# (Spring Boot 2.7.18) After running the application, something filling in the Eden Space

Tags: java, spring-boot, jvm, garbage-collection, visualvm

You can see the executed application code in https://github.com/JadeKim042386/AccountService.

[Environment]

- Mac M1
- JDK 17 / G1 GC

[VM Options]

- `-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m`

I just ran this application and checked GC with VisualVM(with VisualGC plugin).

[image]
[image]

I want to know what keeps filling in Eden Space. Is there any way I can figure it out?

Comment: Well you are using H2 in-memory as well as a Redis server in the same JVM. Those take space. Look at the threads which hold/keep the memory. Else use a better profiler and take a snapshot and analyze that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks. Can you recommend a profiler?

Comment: That Eden fills up is the normal behaviour of all Java applications. New objects are created in Eden all the time (even if only using VisualVM to observe the JVM and by some other background threads) and most of them turn into garbage shortly after being created. The GC only runs if Eden is full, which is what you see at the right end of the Eden graph. The Eden graph shows live and dead objects.

Comment: @ThomasKläger do create a new object every time even if already have the same object in eden?

Comment: New objects are created every time some java code executes `new XY()` - it doesn't matter whether an identical objects already exists (or existed).

Comment: @ThomasKläger  so... Is there a way to know what is creating? In some java applications, the eden space is filled quickly, so I want to know.

Comment: Your application seems to be a web-application. In web-applications every incoming request probably creates hundreds of objects. You are monitoring your application using VisualVM. VisualVM sends several requests per second to your application which also creates hundreds of objects. Tracing Eden doesn't pay of since most objects are created and shortly after that discarded (that is the main point why Java uses generational garbage collectors.) You have a problem if the old generation starts to fill up.

Comment: There is no such thing as “the same object” when using `new`. The `new` operator creates an object with a distinct identity. There can’t be an identical object. Besides that creating new objects is as normal as invoking methods in Java. It happens all the time. Even the JMX communication you are using to monitor your application creates new objects.—Edit: just noticed that Thomas Kläger already said the same.